# performing statistical analysis in python

Tags: python, plot, statistics, dataset

I have an excel spread sheet in the format of a csv file. It has eight columns each corresponding to a unique parameter. The parameter of interest is in column 8. The excel describes the behaviour of a power system with the 8th column describing if a fault occurred what the cascading event would be. I ahve managed to use Pandas to extract the data for which code i will also provide.
a row from the excel spreadsheet can be seen below

143 is the simulation number contained in the first column.

Line 16 - 19 is in the second column.

0.7 is the third column.

0 is the fourth column.

0.5 is the fifth column.

0.5 is the sixth column.

1 is the 7th column and is either 1 or 0 in value depending if there is a fault- is 1 if the element contains a fault.

[('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.65'), ('Load 23A_UF', '11.87'), ('Load 21A_UF', '11.87'), ('Load 24A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 16A_UF', '11.88')..........is the eighth column and contains the reason for the fault.

within the eighth column there is a list held in brackets. The bracket contains three values, the first being what element caused the fault, the second being the reason- in some cases there is no reason and so it is blank and the third being the time the fault occurred. I have used pandas to gather the infomation from within the 8th columns.

Here is an example of the full layout

143 Line 16 - 19    0.7 0   0.5 0.5 1   [('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.65'), ('Load 23A_UF', '11.87'), ('Load 21A_UF', '11.87'), ('Load 24A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 16A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 25A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 26A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 27A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 28A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 29A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 18A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 15A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 03A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 04A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 12A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 08A_UF', '11.88'), ('Load 07A_UF', '11.88')]

[Excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lmU1.png)

the eighth column has been dealt with as so...

```
def list_dir(self, pattern = "*"):
import glob
return [Path(x) for x in glob.glob(str(self/pattern))]
Path.ls = list_dir
CSVFiles = Path('CSVFiles')
def CSV_to_Panda_Dataframe(file):
df = pd.read_csv(file)
return df
df = CSV_to_Panda_Dataframe(CSVFiles/"results_summary.csv")
df.head()
df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=True)
df.head()
for row in df.itertuples():
 print(row._8)
for row in df.itertuples():
if row._8 == "[]":
    continue
else:
    print("Simulation #-", row._1, ": ", row._8)
```

All the information in the eighth column is then displayed as follows...

```
Simulation #- 7.0 :  [('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.70')]
Simulation #- 20.0 :  [('G 01', 'Out of Step', '2.58')]
Simulation #- 31.0 :  [('G 02', 'UV', '2.73'), ('G 01', 'Out of Step', '3.16')]
Simulation #- 41.0 :  [('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.63'), ('Load 23A_UF', '11.37'), ('Load 21A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 08A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 07A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 12A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 24A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 15A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 16A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 04A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 03A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 18A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 25A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 27A_UF', '11.39'), ('Load 26A_UF', '11.39')]
Simulation #- 75.0 :  [('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.65'), ('Load 25A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 03A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 26A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 27A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 18A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 16A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 24A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 23A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 21A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 28A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 15A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 29A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 04A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 08A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 07A_UF', '12.87'), ('Load 12A_UF', '12.87')]
Simulation #- 103.0 :  [('NSG_2', 'OverVoltage', '2.07')]
Simulation #- 105.0 :  [('NSG_2', 'OverVoltage', '2.11')]
Simulation #- 106.0 :  [('NSG_2', 'OverVoltage', '2.09')]
Simulation #- 109.0 :  [('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.63'), ('Load 29A_UF', '10.65'), ('Load 28A_UF', '10.66'), ('Load 26A_UF', '10.67'), ('Load 08A_UF', '10.79'), ('Load 12A_UF', '10.79'), ('Load 07A_UF', '10.79'), ('Load 23A_UF', '10.80'), ('Load 04A_UF', '10.80'), ('Load 21A_UF', '10.81')]
Simulation #- 110.0 :  [('NSG_2', 'OverVoltage', '2.04')]
Simulation #- 111.0 :  [('NSG_2', 'OverVoltage', '2.00')]
```

I then try to extract each reason from between the [] as so... not the best way as I am not cycling through the list.

```
    import re

ini_list = "[('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.63'), ('Load 23A_UF', '11.37'), ('Load 21A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 08A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 07A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 12A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 24A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 15A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 16A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 04A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 03A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 18A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 25A_UF', '11.38'), ('Load 27A_UF', '11.39'), ('Load 26A_UF', '11.39')]"

#extract all tuples by regular expression
result = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)',ini_list)

target_list = []
for tup in result:
    item = tup.split(',')
    if len(item) == 3:
        target_list.append((item[0], item[1], item[2]))
    else:
        target_list.append((item[0], None, item[1]))
    reason = item[0]
    re_reason = reason.strip('()')
#res_reason = reason.strip('(')[1]
    print(re_reason)
```

i then get the result of the first element of each bracket like so....

'G 05'
'Load 23A_UF'
'Load 21A_UF'
'Load 08A_UF'
'Load 07A_UF'
'Load 12A_UF'
'Load 24A_UF'
'Load 15A_UF'
'Load 16A_UF'
'Load 04A_UF'

Not sure how to just get the faults to do the comparisons

I would like to do some basic statistical analysis by determine what faults are the most prevalent and how many faults occur. for example:
count how many simulations run and then work out the total percentage of faults that happen out of all simulations, further more determine out of these faults what faults are the most common and what elements (first item held within the list within the bracket) seem to be most prevalent when a fault occurs. Out of all the faults what percentage of the total faults that occur are due to over-speed, overvoltage, undervoltage, under-speed etc. column 7 will contain a 1 if there is a fault.

I have tried to get a few stats as follows but am very new to python and struggling a huge amount and not even sure if what I am doing is even the best approach. Would really like a tidy way to display the faults and percentage of faults that occur. Another thing to note not all simulations have faults and the number of faults that occur change. some instances have 2 while others can have as many as 8. Additionally the faults contained in the brackets do not always contain three elements of data, some cases have two and the reason for tripping is omitted. However the lay out is ('element', 'reason', 'time') but some cases are in the form ('element', 'time'). would be great to see the total percentage of elements that also seem to be prone to faults more than others.

```
    directory = r'C:\Users\ywb18201\Desktop\Paper\Results 2019new\\'
#directory = r'C:\Users\ywb18201\Desktop\Paper\Results All\\'
k,l=0,0
total_cases=23958

cascades=[]
num=[]
times=0
#filename=r'\results_tap_load=1.1_wind=0.0_0.0_0.0.csv'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(directory+filename) as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            casc_seq = []
            if len(row)>2 and '(' in row[0] and 'Load' not in row[2]:
                k = 2
                if 'Load' in row[2] or 'Line' in row[2]:
                    k = 3
                for i in range(k,len(row)):
                    casc_dec=row[i].split(',')
                    if len(casc_dec)>2:
                        casc=casc_dec[0]+'-'+casc_dec[1]
                    else:
                        casc=casc_dec[0]
                    if str(casc)[2:]=='':
                        print(str(casc)[2:])
                        print(filename)
                    if str(casc)[2:] not in casc_seq:
                        casc_seq.append(str(casc)[2:])
                # for i,item in enumerate(casc_seq):
                #     if 'Load' in item:
                #         casc_seq[i]='Load'
                if len(casc_seq)!=0:
                    if casc_seq not in cascades:
                        cascades.append(casc_seq)
                        num.append(1)
                        times+=1
                    else:
                        num[cascades.index(casc_seq)]+=1


type=[]
counterv,counterf,countervf=0,0,0
for item in cascades:
    f1,f2=0,0
    for casc in item:
        if 'UV' in casc or 'Voltage' in casc:
            f1=1
        elif 'UF' in casc or 'Frequency' in casc or 'Speed' in casc:
            f2=1
    if f1==1:
        if f2==1:
            type.append('voltage and frequency')
            countervf+=1
        else:
            type.append('voltage')
            counterv+=1
    else:
        type.append('frequency')
        counterf+=1

firstv=0
firstf=0
for item in cascades:
    if 'UV' in item[0] or 'Voltage' in item[0]:
        firstv+=1
    elif 'UF' in item[0] or 'Frequency' in item[0] or 'Speed' in item[0]:
        firstf += 1


# for i,item in enumerate(cascades):
#     print(num[i],item,type[i])
print(times)
# print(sum(num))
# print(max(num),cascades[num.index(max(num))])

# cascadesnew=[]
# numnew=[]
# timesnew=0
# for item in cascades:
#     items = []
#     for casc in item:
#         if 'Load' not in casc:
#             items.append(casc)
#     if items in cascadesnew:
#         numnew[cascadesnew.index(items)]+=1
#     else:
#         cascadesnew.append(items)
#         numnew.append(1)
#         timesnew+=1
#
# numnew, cascadesnew = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(numnew, cascadesnew))))
#
# for i,item in enumerate(cascadesnew):
#     print(numnew[i],item)
# print(timesnew)
# print(sum(numnew))


flat_list = [item for sublist in cascades for item in sublist]
flat1=[]
for item in flat_list:
    if 'Line' not in item:
        if 'NSG_3' in item:
            flat1.append('NSG_3-UnderVoltage')
        elif 'NSG_1' in item:
            flat1.append('NSG_1-UnderVoltage')
        elif 'G2_UV' in item:
            flat1.append('G2_UV')
        elif 'G1_UV' in item:
            flat1.append('G1_UV')
        else:
            flat1.append(item)
flat_list=flat1
B=Counter(flat_list)
res=B.most_common()
print(res)


labels, values = zip(*res)
values=[161*item/1357-5 for item in values]
indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.5
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
bar=plt.bar(indexes, values, width)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=6)
plt.xticks(indexes , labels, rotation=90)
for rect in bar:
    height = rect.get_height()
    plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2.0, height, '%d' % int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.ylabel('Number of patterns')
plt.xlabel('Protection device')
plt.show()


# labels=['Voltage and Frequency','Voltage','Frequency']
# values = [countervf,counterv,counterf]
# indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
# width = 0.5
# plt.title('Number of Voltage or Frequency related sequences')
# bar=plt.bar(indexes, values, width)
# #plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=8)
# plt.xticks(indexes , labels, )
# for rect in bar:
#     height = rect.get_height()
#     plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2.0, height, '%d' % int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')
# plt.tight_layout()
# plt.show()
#
#
# labels=['Voltage','Frequency']
# values = [firstv,firstf]
# indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
# width = 0.5
# plt.title('Reason for the first trip in sequence')
# bar=plt.bar(indexes, values, width)
# plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=8)
# plt.xticks(indexes , labels, )
# for rect in bar:
#     height = rect.get_height()
#     plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2.0, height, '%d' % int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')
# plt.tight_layout()
# plt.show()
```

i have also tried to do various plots by trying to recycle old code from a similar project to get the number of faults and what they are related to.

```
import os
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

directory = r'C:\Users\ywb18201\Desktop\Paper\Results 20191.3new\\'
k,l=0,0
total_cases=23958

windv=[]
cascades=[]
num=1331*[0]
times=0
lines=[]
ftimes=[]
vtimes=[]
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    windsum=filename.split('=')[2]
    #a=windsum.split('_')[0]*49.5+windsum.split('_')[1]*38.4+windsum.split('_')[2][:-4]*25.6
    a=float(windsum.split('_')[0])*49.5+float(windsum.split('_')[1])*38.4+float(windsum.split('_')[2][:-4])*25.6
    #print('%.1f'%a)
    #windv.append('%.2f'%a)
    windv.append(a/113.5*100)
    with open(directory+filename) as csvfile:
        casc_len=0
        countv,countf=0,0
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            casc_seq = []
            if len(row) > 2 and '(' in row[0] and 'Load' not in row[2]:
                k = 2
                if 'Load' in row[2] or 'Line' in row[2]:
                    k = 3
                if len(row)-k>0:
                    firstline=row[0]
                    lines.append(firstline[2:-13])
                for i in range(k, len(row)):
                    casc_dec = row[i].split(',')
                    if len(casc_dec) > 2:
                        casc = casc_dec[0] + '-' + casc_dec[1]
                    else:
                        casc = casc_dec[0]
                    if str(casc)[2:] == '':
                        print(str(casc)[2:])
                        print(filename)
                    if str(casc)[2:] not in casc_seq:
                        casc_seq.append(str(casc)[2:])
                    if 'UnderVoltage' in casc or 'UV' in casc:
                        countv+=1
                    elif 'UF' in casc or 'Machine' in casc:
                        countf+=1
                casc_len=casc_len+len(casc_seq)
        #print(casc_len- countv-countf)
        cascades.append(casc_len)
        vtimes.append(countv)
        ftimes.append(countf)


print(cascades)
print([x + y for x, y in zip(vtimes, ftimes)])
#print(ftimes)
# B=Counter(lines)
# res=B.most_common()
#
# labels, values = zip(*res)
# indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
# width = 0.5
# plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 24})
# bar=plt.bar(indexes, values, width)
# plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=6)
# plt.xticks(indexes , labels)
# for rect in bar:
#     height = rect.get_height()
#     plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2.0, height, '%d' % int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')
# plt.tight_layout()
# plt.ylabel('Number of Cascading Events')
# plt.xlabel('Fault Location')
# plt.show()
windvf,windvv=windv,windv
windv, cascades = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(windv, cascades))))

windvf, ftimes = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(windvf, ftimes))))
windvv, vtimes = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(windvv, vtimes))))


labels=windv
values = np.arange(len(labels))
#plt.plot(values,cascades,'bo',markersize=2)
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
p1=plt.bar(values,cascades,width=1, label="130% Loading")
#plt.xticks(values, labels)
#plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1332, 100))
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(values), max(values)+1, 133),[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
plt.ylabel('Number of Protection Devices that tripped')
plt.xlabel('Wind Generation Output Percentage (%)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()



ind = np.arange(len(windv))    # the x locations for the groups
width = 1     # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
p1 = plt.bar(ind, vtimes, width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, ftimes, width, bottom=vtimes)
#p4 = plt.bar(ind, cascades, width=1)

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(ind), max(ind)+1, 133),[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
#plt.yticks([])
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Voltage Related', 'Frequency Related'))
plt.ylabel('Number of Protection Devices that tripped')
plt.xlabel('Wind Generation Output Percentage (%)')
plt.show()
```

I appreciate this is quite a complex task and the data set is set up in a really tricky format however the data set cannot be changed. Any help will be so greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should seriously consider using pandas for your data analisys.

Here are some tutorials that I used to learn pandas.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyhVh-qRZPA&list=PL-osiE80TeTsWmV9i9c58mdDCSskIFdDS

You can separate the the 8th column (which seems to be the most troublesome) into more columns, and if there are some missing data (as it is said in your question) you can always use some tools in pandas that can measure that missing data as well.

I have provided a broad answer because your question is broad. My advice is that you try out pandas, and if you get stuck, you can always come back here and ask a specific question to pull through.

Comment: i have managed to use the pandas to extract the data into this format:Simulation #- 7.0 :  [('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.70')]
Simulation #- 20.0 :  [('G 01', 'Out of Step', '2.58')]
Simulation #- 31.0 :  [('G 02', 'UV', '2.73'), ('G 01', 'Out of Step', '3.16')]
Simulation #- 41.0 :  [('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.63'), ('Load 23A_UF', '11.37')]

Comment: Nice, if you don't know how to continue, post the code that you have used (with pandas) and ask what you would like to happen next. For example: 'I have loaded the data in this way, and now I would like to separate them into colums', or 'I would like to filter the dataframe based on a value in this column'.

Comment: Even If you end up finding what you need, I strongly recommend you to spend 5-6 hours learning pandas in general, because you might learn things that currently you don't know that you need. And once you know them, it will make everything easier, and might even provide information about your data that you didn't know that you needed.

Comment: Perfect thank you for the advice I will review that link you posted. I uploaded the code I have just added to get the info from the simulations just a bit unsure how to strip the brackets off and get the info I actually want from it as I get errors stating that list does not strip etc because I actually just want to get the reason (type of fault from each simulation)